# Loop runs only once first time it's called, infinite second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops

I've created a loop that runs while waiting for a user to fill out boxes in an alert before the code moves on. I use the same loops elsewhere and it works perfectly.

Here however, it only loops once the first time it's called, subsequently creating another alert and getting called again.

The second time it runs until the user has finished entering their details as it should.

```
//Method waiting for users credentials
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
{
    NSLog(@"got auth challange");
    _didChallenge = YES;

    // Ask user for their credentials
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" message:@"Please enter username and password:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alertView setTag:1];
    alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
    [alertView show];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(WaitForCredentialDialog) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    //... Code to deal with credentials is here.
}

//Here dialogResult is a variable which will make while loop run until its value is -1 and reset its value to 1 or 0 when AlertView's Button is clicked
- (void) WaitForCredentialDialog{
    NSDate* LoopUntil;
    LoopUntil = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];
    while ((dialogResult==-1) && ([[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:LoopUntil]))
    {
        LoopUntil = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using 100% CPU to just wait for a credentials input?  Ouch.

Comment: The only advice I can offer is that the approach is all wrong.   You should be using `UIAlertView`'s delegate to get notified when the user has finished entering their credentials (or decided not to) and not putting the run loop into a waiting state.

Comment: When I previously tried to wait for user input, what would happen is after `[alertView show]`, the code would just continue into the if else clause before the OK button had even been pressed..

Comment: That's because UIAlertView doesn't block the run loop (nor should it).  You should be handling the credentials in the delegate call once the user has signaled they're finished entering them.  You can also find a number of block-based `UIAlertView` categories but you should learn the delegate pattern first.

Comment: Ok, I've changed it to use the delegate methods. However `didRecieveAuthenticationChallenge` is still being called multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **should not use loops** for that! Use the `UITextFieldDelegate` to get events about what user typed.

#### Example

To detect changes in the text field use:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Or `UIAlertViewDelegate`'s:

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
```

This method is called both when the alert view is first displayed and also each time the user types a character into one of the text fields, making it very easy to perform basic input validation prior to accepting a user's value.

Source:

- [UIAlertViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:)
- [UITextFieldDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)